# Typescript: undefined is not assignable to return while undefined cannot be returned

Tags: typescript

I have following piece of code that pulls environment variables via dotenv, can substitute it, if it does not exist and `defaultValue` is passed or throws error if neither of them contain value. This creates a scenario where execution either crashes or it returns valid value.

```
const getEnvironmentVariable = (
  variable: string,
  defaultValue?: string|number,
): string | number => {
  if((process.env[variable] === undefined) && defaultValue === undefined){
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    throw new Error(`Mandatory environment variable ${variable} was not set.`)  
  }
  
  if(
    process.env[variable] === undefined 
    && defaultValue !== undefined
  ) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console, max-len
    console.info(`Environment variable ${variable} was not set. Using default: ${defaultValue}`)
  }
  return process.env[variable] ?? defaultValue
}
```

But I am getting following error on return, even tho it will never happen, that undefined will be returned.

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.

Comment: Outside the conditions the type of `defaultValue` is still `string | number | undefined`, because it's optional. Just reorganise the function so the compiler can follow the control flow: https://tsplay.dev/NDDk6N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't understand the concept of: "If this variable is undefined, it means that the other one is not."

To Typescript this just means the both of the variables can be undefined.

Another issue you might encounter is that `process.env[variable]` will always return `string | undefined` even though you checked in on a previous line. you should therefore store it in a `const`. Here is an example that should work:

```js
const getEnvironmentVariable = (
  variable: string,
  defaultValue?: string | number,
): string | number => {
  const environmentVariable = process.env[variable]
  
  if (environmentVariable === undefined) {
    if (defaultValue === undefined) {
      throw new Error(
        `Mandatory environment variable ${variable} was not set.`,
      );
    }
    console.info(
      `Environment variable ${variable} was not set. Using default: ${defaultValue}`
    );
    return defaultValue;
  }
  return environmentVariable;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this does solve the problem, unless better solution pops up, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

After the first `if`, `defaultValue` is still `string | number | undefined` because of the `and`.

Since `process.env[variable] === undefined` could be false, the second operand is not checked.

The same for the second `if`, in order to check for `defaultValue === undefined` you have to split the `if`s:

```
const getEnvironmentVariable = (
  variable: string,
  defaultValue?: string|number,
): string | number => {
  if(process.env[variable] === undefined) {

    if(defaultValue === undefined) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
      throw new Error(`Mandatory environment variable ${variable} was not set.`)  
    }

    if(defaultValue) {
      console.info(`Environment variable ${variable} was not set. Using default: ${defaultValue}`)
      return defaultValue;
    }
  }
  
  return process.env[variable];
}
```

Comment: I feel like you are on the right track, but the error still persists with this solution. For now I will edit the solution that was given by jonrsharpe, seeing that my solution is extremely overengineered.

Comment: @MalwareMoon can you give us a playground link?

Comment: I am afraid not, I did try, but it's hard for me to substitute behavior that I am experiencing with another piece of code and I could not find bare sandboxes with dotenv and typescript.